# Error with my first android app on eclipse neon: nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I just install eclipse neon and the android sdk.

Go to -> file -> new -> android project.

set the settings:
project name etc...
push finish and then i get the next error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'HelloAndroide'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I push on clean and i get the same error.

jdk 112 and i test with 111
windows home premium 7 64 bits